# "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer when webpack is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpacker

**What is the current behavior?**

Webpack returns error provided below when webpack is called both with `cli` and `webpack` function. Strange thing is that it started returning this error after reinstalling node modules.

**If the current behavior is a bug, please provide the steps to reproduce.**:

`webpack --config=./configs/webpack.config.lib.js`

```
throw new TypeError('"string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer');
    ^

TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer
    at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:481:11)
    at RawSource.size (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/Source.js:18:17)
    at obj.assets.compilationAssets.map (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js:415:20)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Stats.toJson (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js:412:6)
    at Stats.toString (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js:857:20)
    at compilerCallback (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:333:32)
    at compiler.run (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:359:7)
    at finalCallback (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at hooks.done.callAsync.err (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:306:14)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at emitRecords.err (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:22)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
    at emitAssets.err (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:298:10)
    at hooks.afterEmit.callAsync.err (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14)
    at _err0 (eval at create (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at callback (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:126:17)
    at afterEmit (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:220:13)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at asyncLib.forEachLimit.err (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:482:27)
    at Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at outputFileSystem.writeFile.err (Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:33)
    at Documents/GitHub/projectName/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:57:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

**Webpack config?**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const packageJSON = require('./package.json');
const srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');
const dstPath = path.join(__dirname, '../out/publish');
const buildMode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    context: srcPath,
    entry: {
        main: [ `${srcPath}/index.ts` ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../out/publish'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        library: packageJSON.name
    },
    mode: buildMode,
    // devtool: buildMode === 'development' ? 'source-map' : '',

    externals: {
        'big.js': true,
        'classnames': true,
        'lodash': true,
        'moment': true,
        'prop-types': true,
        'react': true,
        'react-dom': true,
        'react-motion': true,
        'react-transition-group': true
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [ srcPath, 'node_modules' ],
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.css' ],
        mainFields: [ 'main', 'browser', 'module' ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|svg|jpg|gif|png|eot)$/,
                use: [ {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 64000
                    }
                } ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: `ts-loader?configFile=${path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.lib.json')}`,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'typed-css-modules-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': '"production"',
                'DEBUG': 'window.envDEBUG'
            },
            __DEV__: false
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'),
                to: `${dstPath}/package.json`
            },
            {
                from: `${srcPath}/core/styles/variables.scss`,
                to: `${dstPath}/variables.scss`
            },
            {
                from: path.join(__dirname, '../README.md'),
                to: `${dstPath}/README.md`
            },
            {
                from: path.join(__dirname, '../CHANGELOG.md'),
                to: `${dstPath}/CHANGELOG.md`
            },
        ]),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),

        new ExtractTextPlugin(`./ui-library.css`)
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    beautify: false,
                    comments: false,
                    sourceMap: true,
                    compress: {
                        sequences: true,
                        booleans: true,
                        loops: true,
                        unused: true,
                        warnings: false,
                        drop_console: true,
                        unsafe: true
                    }
                }
            }),
        ]
    }
};
```

**Other relevant information:**

- webpack version:  `4.41.0` occurs for `3.12.0` too, works fine on
  `3.11.0`
- Node.js version: `dubnium -> v10.17.0`
- Operating System: `MACOS 10.14.2 (18C54)`

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: Included in description.